# How to call a customer who presents a good chance to acquire another customer after a succesful project?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

I'm looking for a term/phrase used in business / business consulting that describes the following situation:

If a successful project has been implemented with customer A, our company is likely to also acquire company B as a customer, e.g. because B is the mother company of A.

Comment: It sounds like A is a "stepping stone" for you.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good! However, there's another term on the tip of my tongue. I remember it being used to state that it's a very important customer that many managers have their eyes on.

Comment: A few words came to mind. Though I'm sure they're not exactly what you're looking for, I will list them out in case they could help a bit: *key customer*, *key prospect*, and *pilot project*.

Comment: Also, if serving company A is not profitable in itself, but only for the sake of trying to woo company B, you could call it a "loss leader."

Answer (score 1):

I can’t think of a single term that captures everything you’ve described.

In the business world, there is a lot of jargon that, beyond being inapplicable outside the realm of business, might not even be understood in a different office or industry.  That said, here is a term you might find useful:

### “in” (noun)

If you were speaking about company A and specifically referring to the opportunity that a relationship with them presents for landing business with company B (of which they happen to be a subsidiary in your example), you could describe company A as an “in”.

> <sup>4</sup>**in** *noun*
> <sup>*chiefly US, informal*</sup>
>   
>  a way of becoming involved in something or of influencing someone
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s Dictionary, definition of “in”](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/in#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_in_4)</sub>

This “in” is usually paired with “with”. Here are two equivalent examples:

> We should really try to get Triscuit’s business. They could be the **in** we need **with** Kraft.

> We should really try to get Triscuit’s business. They could be our **in with** Kraft.

You could also say that company A would allow you to [*get your foot in the door*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+foot+in+the+door) with company B.

Answer (score 0):

They could be referred to as a *gateway* or a *gatekeeper* customer: once you have passed  their requirements, you now have access to a much broader range of opportunities.